Animated emojies in python-telegram-bot
how to add animated emojies in python-telegram-bot?
The normal emojies are working, but how to add the animated ones? I am stuck in this trouble.
I am using the python-telegram-bot async module.
I appriciate for all  the answers below.
Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
